# Use variable as property name (for example in angular router)

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to use a string variable as outlet name in the angular router?
I would like to use something like this:

```
const outletName = 'myrouteroutlet';
this.router.navigate([
      { outlets: { myrouteroutlet: ['pathname'] } },
    ]);
```

But the variable does not get interpreted as variable but as property name, so the router tries to find an outlet named outletName instead of myrouteroutlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the variable's **value** instead of variable's **name** as key, wrap the key in `[` `]`. So, this would be:

```
const outletName = 'myrouteroutlet';
this.router.navigate([
    { outlets: { [outletName]: ['pathname'] } },
]);
```

This would be the same as: `{ outlets: { myrouteroutlet: ['pathname'] } }`. This works not just in routes but in a lot of places.